# Changing inputs to responsive divs in calculator form

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Currently I am using the following code to produce a functional calculator on my website:

```
function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "0")
    input.value = character
  else
    input.value += character
}

function cos(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.cos(form.display.value);
}

function sin(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.sin(form.display.value);
}

function tan(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.tan(form.display.value);
}

function sqrt(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.sqrt(form.display.value);
}

function ln(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.log(form.display.value);
}

function exp(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.exp(form.display.value);
}

function deleteChar(input) {
  input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1)
}

function changeSign(input) {
  if (input.value.substring(0, 1) == "-")
    input.value = input.value.substring(1, input.value.length)
  else
    input.value = "-" + input.value
}

function compute(form) {
  form.display.value = eval(form.display.value)
}

function square(form) {
  form.display.value = eval(form.display.value) * eval(form.display.value)
}

function checkNum(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var ch = str.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (ch < "0" || ch > "9") {
      if (ch != "/" && ch != "*" && ch != "+" && ch != "-" && ch != "." && ch != "(" && ch != ")") {
        alert("invalid entry!")
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}

$('#button-exp').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    exp(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-divide').click(function() {
  addChar(this.form.display, '/')
});

$('#button-ln').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    ln(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-sqrt').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    sqrt(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-minus').click(function() {
  addChar(this.form.display, '-')
});

$('#button-multiply').click(function() {
  addChar(this.form.display, '*')
});

$('#button-square').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    square(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-dot').click(function() {
  addChar(this.form.display, '.')
});

$('#button-plus').click(function() {
   addChar(this.form.display, '+')
});

$('#button-pos').click(function() {
  changeSign(this.form.display)
});

$('#button-cos').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    cos(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-sin').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    sin(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-tan').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    tan(this.form)
  }
});

$('#button-cb').click(function() {
   addChar(this.form.display, ')')
});


$('#button-clear').click(function() {
  this.form.display.value = 0
});


$('#button-bsp').click(function() {
  deleteChar(this.form.display)
});

$('#button-enter').click(function() {
  if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
    compute(this.form)
  }
});

$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], function(i, e) {
  $('#button-' + e).click(function() {
    addChar(this.form.display, e);
  });
});
```

With the HTML:

```
<FORM NAME="sci-calc">
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="1">
    <TR>
      <td COLSPAN="5" ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT NAME="display" VALUE="0" ID="disp" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25"/>
      </td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID='button-exp' VALUE=" e<sup>x</sup>"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-log" VALUE="  log  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-7" VALUE="  7  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-8" VALUE="  8  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-9" VALUE="  9  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-divide" VALUE="   &#247;   "/>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-ln" VALUE="   ln   "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-4" VALUE="  4  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-5" VALUE="  5  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-6" VALUE="  6  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-multiply" VALUE="   &#215;   "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id="button-percent" VALUE="&#37;" />
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-sqrt" VALUE=" &radic; "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-1" VALUE="  1  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-2" VALUE="  2  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-3" VALUE="  3  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-minus" VALUE="   &#8722;   "/>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-square" VALUE="  x&sup2;  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-cube" VALUE="  x&sup3;  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-0" VALUE="  0  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-dot" VALUE="   .  "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-pos" VALUE=" +/&#8722; "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-plus" VALUE="   +  "/>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-ob" VALUE="    (    "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-cos" VALUE="cos"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-sin" VALUE=" sin"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-tan" VALUE=" tan"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-cb" VALUE="   )   "/>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-clear" VALUE="C"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-pi" VALUE="&#960;"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID='button-factorial' VALUE=" x! "/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-bsp" VALUE="&#9003;"/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-enter" VALUE="="/>
      </TD>
      <TD ALIGN="center">
        <INPUT TYPE="button"  ID="button-2nd" VALUE=" 2nd "/>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

I am wondering is it possible to change these inputs to divs without losing functionality? If so, how might the javascript/jQuery look?

Comment: It could be done by what do you need that?

Comment: You can change the *table* to divs, not the *inputs* (if you really want that, you could do that too, but it would be difficult, ugly and an unjustified difficulty). And as far as I can see, as long as you keep the form, the input elements and the IDs, you can do to the table whatever you want, since the JS doesn't rely on it.

Comment: I ask because I am hoping to add some buttons with superscripts not defined in Unicode (cos^-1, for example). The input value attribute does not accept HTML tags like *sup* so this has become somewhat of a conundrum for me. If I use divs I can avoid that, but I cannot figure out how to alter the code so that the functions still execute (I am assuming it has something to do with those functions that include *input.value*, but again, being new to Javascript, I am not sure how to alter them.

Comment: you can try `<button>cos^-1</button>` instead, this gives you more flexibility and you can wrapped it around other html element as well

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/22sc8xfu/1/